# Bet365.com is not loading in QWebEngineView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage, qwebengine

```
class MyWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        print("interceptRequest")
        print(info.requestUrl())

class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame):
        print("acceptNavigationRequest")
        print(url)
        return QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame)

     def certificateError(self, certificateError):
       print(certificateError.errorDescription(), certificateError.url(), certificateError.isOverridable())
       error = certificateError.error()

       return super(MyWebEnginePage, self).certificateError(certificateError)    

class Browser(QMainWindow):
    proxy_type = QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy
    proxy_hostname = 'proxy_hostname'
    proxy_port = 64777
    proxy_username = 'proxy_username'
    proxy_password = 'proxy_username'

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.searching_url = url
        self.set_auth_proxy()
        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()

        self.setMinimumSize(1200, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webEngineView)

        interceptor = MyWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()

        profile = QWebEngineProfile('storage', self.webEngineView)

        profile.setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)

        url = QUrl(self.searching_url)
        url.setScheme("http")
        url.setHost("www.bet365.com")
        httpReq = QWebEngineHttpRequest()
        httpReq.setUrl(url)
        httpReq.setMethod(QWebEngineHttpRequest.Get)
        httpReq.setHeader(QByteArray(b'Accept'), QByteArray(b'*/*'))
        
        httpReq.setHeader(QByteArray(b'Content-Type'), QByteArray(b'application/json'))
        httpReq.setHeader(QByteArray(b'User-Agent'), QByteArray(b'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'))

        print(httpReq.header(QByteArray(b'Host')))

        page = MyWebEnginePage(profile, self.webEngineView)
        self.webEngineView.setPage(page)

        self.show()
        self.webEngineView.load(httpReq)

    def set_auth_proxy(self):
        self.auth_proxy = QNetworkProxy()
        self.auth_proxy.setType(self.proxy_type)
        self.auth_proxy.setHostName(self.proxy_hostname)
        self.auth_proxy.setPort(self.proxy_port)
        self.auth_proxy.setUser(self.proxy_username)
        self.auth_proxy.setPassword(self.proxy_password)
        self.auth_proxy.setApplicationProxy(self.auth_proxy)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bet365 = 'https://www.bet365.com'    
    postman = 'http://postman-echo.com/get'

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser(bet365)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the browser code, which should just open the page bet365.com but the problem is that the page does not load, the program window becomes just white, while other sites, such as 2ip.ru is loaded and shows my IP. What can I do to get bet365 to answer me correctly?

Screenshot of white window:
[image: Screenshot of white window]

Also when I set the Host header like this
`httpReq.setHeader(QByteArray(b'Host'), QByteArray(b'www.bet365.com'))`, there is an error with the code ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT, I thought it was still about the headers when requesting, but no, I have set different headers and no luck.